# javascript: calling same function at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing this javascript code for awhile which it only run a function once when the button is click.

> JAVASCRIPT:

```
var a = 1;

function add(name) 
{
if (a <= 9) 
    {
        a++;
        var parent = name.parentNode;
        var content = parent.querySelector("div");
        var str = content.innerHTML;
        str = str.replace(/_1/gi, '_' + a);
        var divtest = document.createElement("div");
        divtest.setAttribute("id", a);
        divtest.innerHTML = str + a;
        parent.appendChild(divtest);
    }
}
```

> HTML:

```
<div id="main1">
<button onclick="add(this);return false;">+</button>
<div id="content1">
A
</div>
</div>

<div id="main2">
<button onclick="add(this);return false;">+</button>
<div id="content2">
B
</div>
</div>
```

The code above only calls the function once but I want it to run the function at the same time.

> OUTPUT:

```
+
A
A 2
A 3
A 4
A 5
A 6
A 7
A 8
A 9
A 10
+
B
```

When I click the button on both divs it should add both on there main divs per click.

> EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
+
A
A 2
A 3
A 4
A 5
A 6
A 7
A 8
A 9
A 10
+
B
B 2
B 3
B 4
B 5
B 6
B 7
B 8
B 9
B 10
```

Comment: using only a number for an `id` is illegal HTML.

Comment: I deleted my answer as I am still unsure what you are asking at this point...

Comment: when i click each button on the div it keeps adding. try to run my script it wont let me add 9 divs in each main1 and main2 divs

Comment: The `a` variable exists for both states. It means in summary you can click only 9 times. You need to save 2 states for different clicks

Comment: @Max how can I click both 9 times on each button?

Comment: what do you mean by  "calling same function at same time" in the title?  When a web browser runs a javascript program, there is only one execution thread.   So, there can never be two parts of the program trying to call the same function at the same time.  Only one thing at a time runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the code is working, this is simple enough:

```
function add(me) 
{
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button.add');
    var btn;
    for(var b = 0; b < buttons.length; b++)
    {
        btn = buttons[b];
        if(me === btn) {
            btn.a = btn.a || 1;
            btn.a++;
            addForButton(btn);
        }
    }
}

function rem(me) 
{
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button.remove');
    var btn;
    for(var b = 0; b < buttons.length; b++)
    {
        btn = buttons[b];
        if(me === btn) {
            var divs = me.parentNode.querySelectorAll('div > div');
            if(divs.length > 1){
                divs[divs.length - 1].parentNode.removeChild(divs[divs.length - 1]);
                btn.a--;
            }
        }
    }
}

function addForButton(name) {
    var parent = name.parentNode;
    var content = parent.querySelector("div");
    if (name.a <= 9) 
    {
        var str = content.innerHTML;
        str = str.replace(/_1/gi, '_' + name.a);
        var divtest = document.createElement("div");
        divtest.setAttribute("id", name.a);
        divtest.innerHTML = str;
        parent.appendChild(divtest);
    }
}
```

Then add IDs to the buttons:

```
<button onclick="add();return false;">+</button>

<button onclick="add();return false;">+</button>
```

Comment: yeah this is what im looking for.  thanks alot. is there any way to remove the add() functions for buttons?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Remove `onclick="add(this);"` ?

Comment: i mean just only 1 function all of them are inside like my OP

Comment: @SpiderPig yeah something like that i can make that as a referrence

Comment: @SpiderPig is there no other way just onclick="adder"? cause if i had alot of buttons i will keep adding on the script.

Comment: What about garryps solution?

Comment: @SpiderPig yeah I like his solution it works and yours works too. but your solution is simplier but i dont want to keep adding to the script when theres alot of button.

Comment: You can always just add onclick handlers to the buttons with javascript. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/Lo0jncp7/

Comment: That's nice an clean :-)

Comment: yeah thanks for the solutions guys. i accept the answer already and i will used all of your answer as my referrence.

Comment: @SpiderPig your solution it submits my form when i click the button. haha can you help me with this?

Comment: I'd need to know what your code looks like. Anyway, here is an updated example that adds the onclick handler only to buttons of a certain type. http://jsfiddle.net/hpv4Lub1/

Comment: just add a form you can see it when you click it it just gonna submit. like my code above i add return false; so it wont submit the form if i click the button

Comment: button type is "submit" by default. If you don't want it to submit the form add the attributes/value type="button" to the `<button>` element `<button type="button">+</button>`